# AdMob AdView and ViewPager?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager, admob, viewpagerindicator

I have Android application with ViewPager implemented like this :

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C6_1KznO95A

I don't know how to implement AdView below the ViewPager.
I have tried to put AdView below the ViewPager programmatically and in xml.
There is no errors but ads are not showing.

My xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="top"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pager"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_publisher_id"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
</com.google.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: please post your xml layout it should come actually..

Answer (score 11):

OK, you have a couple of problems.

1. orientation is only relevant for a LinearLayout.
2. layout_alignParentBottom needs a boolean value not "top"
3. layout_weight is only relevant for a LinearLayout nor RelativeLayout

You have 2 options. Use a RelativeLayout but define the AdView first with the ViewPager being defined as above it OR use a LinearLayout and have the ViewPager fill the unused space using layout_weight.

As RelativeLayout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_publisher_id"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ad"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

OR as LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_publisher_id"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Personally I'd go with the LinearLayout it feels simpler.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
    AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad);
    adView.bringToFront();
```